# Google API for checking Google Groups' Name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-groups-api

I want to write a script to get my all Google Groups (not Google Contacts). My code is like below,

```
function checkGroupisExist(){
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var groups = GroupsApp.getGroups();
   console.info(groups.length);
   var boo=false; 

   var Avals = sheet.getRange("B1:B").getValues();
   var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;


  for (var i = 2; i< Alast; i++){
        var columnEmailName = sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue()+"@****.com"; //Group email
        var columnGroupName = sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue(); //Group email

    for (var j = 0; j< groups.length; j++) {
            console.info(groups[j].getEmail()+" "+ j);
          if(groups[j].getEmail()==columnEmailName){
             console.info(groups[j].getEmail()); 
             console.info('The group are equal ->' +groups[j].getEmail()+ '' +columnEmailName); 

           }


   }



  }



}
```

However, I see the GroupsApp.getGroups() method returns groups which I am member of them, so it is not the correct method that I want to use check all the groups name. Do you guys know any API to get the all Google Groups' name in my account?

Comment: You say you want to write code to get the "names" of all *your* Google Groups.. but then say that `GroupsApp.getGroups()` - which returns a list of all Google Groups you are a member of - is not right. I'm not sure what you mean by that statement.

Comment: To me, what you are asking to do is literally the example code provided for [`Group#getEmail()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/group#getEmail()). If not, it seems like you need to try [`GroupsApp#getGroupByEmail`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/groups-app#getGroupByEmail(String)) and handle any thrown exceptions. Or, are you in a GSuite domain, and looking for 
 its Google Groups API? https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups